# Example of list having texts with images in android

Tags: android

I am developing a small list android application in which i have texts and images.Can anyone tell how should i pursue

Thanks in advance
Tushar

Comment: do you want to show list on screen or just want to save data in a list???

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html. Lists in android are not discriminatory - you can have several types of objects in them, just try to remember/ keep track of what kind of object you have in each place.

In order to add an element to the list it would be something like this

```
List myList = new List();    
myList.add(9);
myList.add("hola");
```

You can take a look at the rest of methods that list implement in the link that is at the beginning of the post.